# Is it possible to set a fluid width for Facebook's social plugins?

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, responsive-design

I'm developing a site around the "responsive design" concept, but the facebook social plugins are static width and "break" the layout when it's re-sized.

Using media queries, I've set the plugins to hide on low-res browsers (mobile, etc...). However, on desktop browsers, when the browser window is re-sized smaller, but not so small to hide the plugins, they break out of the layout.

Any way to set a fluid width for the Facebook social plugins?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The correct working answer is a combination of things I found here. Mikel's answer is a good start:

[Facebook Developers Platform link](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/256568534516879/)

This says:

> We have pushed a fix for this. From now on, you can specify the width
>   as 100% (e.g. data-width="100%") to get a fluid layout. Docs are
>   updated too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments 
>   Thanks for your patience.

But... This will load the width of what's available to the plugin at loading time. When you resize your page it will remain the same width it had when you loaded the page. To fix this - and make a true responsive version of the Facebook Social Plugin - Add the following in your CSS:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span {
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

This will cause the plugin to resize to the available space as you resize the window.

If you want this code to work for the page plugin, change the class-name 'fb-comments' to 'fb-page':

```
.fb-page, .fb-page iframe[style], .fb-page span {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

(thanks for the addition Black_Stormy!)

Comment: Works perfect for me too! Thank you !!
Is it possible to reflect this things on like-share plugins too ?

Comment: This works on the page plugin, provided you change the class names from 'fb-comments' to 'fb-page'. Making the above css: `.fb-page, .fb-page iframe[style], .fb-page span {
   width: 100% !important;
}`

Comment: With this code the whole _wrapper_ element  of the plugin is responsive, but the content itself it's not, if the page is resized it will get cropped.
Guess I'm missing something very obvious but how can I make also the content of the `Iframe` fluid?

Comment: Facebook suggests rerendering the content, but I'm not sure how to do that. `FB.XFBML.parse()` is close, but seems extremely sloppy.

Comment: Actually, might have figured out a workaround, writing a real answer

Answer (score 62):

none of these methods worked but using this idea, the following worked for me:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments span, .fb-comments.fb_iframe_widget span iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This no longer works. Facebook now sets the width of a div inside the iframe.

Comment: good to know... thanks!  I'll try and update my answer next chance I get.

Comment: I combined this with data-width="100%". And worked like a charm.

Comment: Please not that the 'accepted answer' that didn't work in 2013 is no longer the accepted answer. The currently accepted answer does work...

Answer (score 56):

I found a solution using css. Inspiration came from this article
http://css-tricks.com/2708-override-inline-styles-with-css/

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style] {width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: Very useful article. None of the answers on this page worked for me, but simply - iframe[style]{width:100% !important;} fixes this in my case. The problem element for me was in #fb-root>div[1]>iframe which had an inline width of 575px;

Comment: Great tip, thank you! I found I had to use this to make it work

.fb-comments,
.fb-comments > span[style],
.fb_iframe_widget iframe[style] {
 width: 100% !important;
}

Comment: Bah! I'm finding that this trick only seems to work intermittently. I'm using Chrome on OSX, and the comments render at 550px width. When I refresh the page they render at full width. Strangely, when I select one of the widget elements in Chrome Developer Tools (Chrome's version of Firebug) the comments magically pop out to full width! Must be some rendering peculiarity of Chrome.

Comment: Had to add `.fb-comments > span` to mine because the span FB adds inside had a width set via a style attribute.

Comment: allenericr is right. So you need to add two lines of CSS:
`.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style] {width: 100% !important;}
.fb-comments, .fb-comments > span[style] {width: 100% !important;}`

Comment: `.fb-comments, .fb-comments span, .fb-comments iframe { width: 100% !important; }` works for me.

Comment: This is no longer a solution, Facebook has changed the way they render the iframe and now they are setting the width inside, so you can have the iframe 100% width but not the content.

Comment: Yep! Trying to figure this one out :/

Comment: Agreed with AlexLopezIT. Facebook sets the width of an ID with the name starting with "feeback_" inside the iframe, which you can't alter. Here is a link with the closest I've seen to a solution yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491401/set-value-for-dynamic-class-in-css-or-jquery

Comment: this can now be done with `data-width="100%"` in the tag. It won't scale as you shrink the window, but it does go to the correct size if you refresh the page at a smaller size.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to make it work by using this code:

```
.fb-like, .fb-like span, .fb-like.fb_iframe_widget span iframe {
    width: 100% !important;

}
```

because in my html file I have this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.yourwebsite.yourdomain" data-send="true"  data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="light" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

Tip: You should change your css depending of the div class.

Comment: This no longer works. Facebook now sets the width of a div inside the iframe.

Comment: this works for me but i have changed .fb-like to .fb-like-box because my container is .fb-like-box.

Answer (score 7):

Although it's an old question, this is now the top Google result for "facebook comment plugin responsive" so it's still relevant.

The workarounds in the other answers aren't needed anymore, as FB have recently (May 2014) fixed this at their end.

From https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/256568534516879/:

> We have pushed a fix for this. From now on, you can specify the width
>   as 100% (e.g. data-width="100%") to get a fluid layout. Docs are
>   updated too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments
>   Thanks for your patience.

So now you can just update your HTML to e.g.

`<div class="fb-comments" data-width="100%" data-href="http://yourpageurl.com"></div>`

And don't need any extra CSS workarounds.

Edit: this will create the plugin to adapt it's width to the available space at load time. When you resize the browser window the plugin will remain at that initial width. To make it true responsive add this to your CSS:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span {
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

This will cause the plugin to adapt to the currently availably space when you resize the browser

Comment: it's a pity this is still static though. By far the best answer since this will still be useful when Facebook ever changes the plugin. But without the extra CSS this doesn't scale dynamically... I have a combination of your solution, with added     .fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span {width: 100% !important;} in the CSS, which made it nicely responsive! Should I edit this answer accordingly?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the official wordpress facebook plugin due to the mobile sniffing facebook do.

> The mobile version will automatically show up when a mobile device
>   user agent is detected. You can turn this behavior off by setting the
>   mobile parameter to false. Please note: the mobile version ignores the
>   width parameter, and instead has a fluid width of 100% in order to
>   resize well in portrait/landscape switching situations. You may need
>   to adjust your CSS for your mobile site to take advantage of this
>   behavior. If preferred, you can still control the width via a
>   container element.
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

You will need to change the facebook/social-plugins/fb-comments.php on line 35.

```
<div class="fb-comments fb-social-plugin" ' . $params . ' data-mobile="false"></div>
```

This will allow you to style with the below.

```
.fb-social-plugin {
    width:98%!important;

}

.fb_iframe_widget span {
    width:100%!important;
}

.fb-comments iframe[style] {width: 100% !important;}
```

It would be nice if they could either fix their mobile version or put a setting on their plugins GUI.

Comment: Does this work with the new facebook code, considering that a div now has a set width inside the iframe?

Answer (score 5):

It will definitely work just for adding `.fb-comments span` in style.

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments span, .fb-comments iframe[style] {width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: Not any longer. See above comments.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer did not work for me.

I found this by Craig Bailey in the comments here:

http://www.wpresponsive.com/how-to-make-facebook-comments-responsive-wordpress

which is perfectly fluid (tested in osx ff & safari, ios6).

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This no longer works either. Facebook now sets the width of a div inside the iframe.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this post is not very old but the answer wasn't working for me. I had to add this to my stylesheet...

```
#fbcomments, .fb_iframe_widget, .fb_iframe_widget[style], .fb_iframe_widget iframe[style], #fbcomments iframe[style] {width: 100% !important;}
```

The .fb_iframe_widget and .fb_iframe_widget[style] both seemed to be important.

Comment: That might have worked in the past, but facebook has updated their code, so this no longer works.

Comment: Ya. This question was from 2 years ago Jayden.

Answer (score 2):

I've got this working using this simple script (see code in link).

https://gist.github.com/2111366

You have to make a few changes to the information so that you are using your Facebook App ID and your page URL.

This solution is using jQuery so you'll have to understand how that work but once you get the script to execute your responsive design will work on page load or when resizing the page.

Answer (score 2):

An important note about this resize stuff: If the Facebook comment script detects that you're on a mobile device it breaks this. But, if you make the `<fb:comments>` tag contain the attribute value `mobile="false"` then (for now) Facebook's scripts will respect your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

For those who prefer using the **HTML5** code for Facebook plugins like the [Activity Feed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/) or [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/):

```
/******* IPHONE PORTRAIT MODE (480px or less) *******/
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .fb_iframe_widget span[style], .fb_ltr[style] {
    width:420px !important;
    }
}
```

- Doesn't work with comments or percentage-based width; stick to the iframe code if you need pure fluidity.
- H/T to [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999013/alan) for the css-tricks link at the top of this page. (:

Answer (score 2):

Just put this either in your CSS file or in your html code with style tags !!!

```
<style>
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-like-box, .fb-like-box iframe[style]{width:100% !important;}
.fb-comments span, .fb-comments iframe span[style], .fb-like-box span, .fb-like-box iframe     span[style]{width: 100% !important;}
</style>
```

Ref: http://dwij.co.in/making-facebook-comments-responsive

Answer (score 2):

Joining the uninformed masses with my own solution to this problem, as of September, 2015:

Facebook provides an option to the `fb-page` widget called `adapt-container-width`, which (according to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin),) should track the parent's width (up to a maximum width of `500px`). When rerendering with `FB.XFBML.parse()`, the widget seems to get stuck on a strange value for the parent's container width, despite what you set on the actual widget itself. For now, this works well enough:

1. Create element using FB's code generator (at the top of [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin))
2. Bind an event to `window`'s `resize` method, (optionally using `_.debounce` with a sensible limit to prevent overloading the browser with the intermediate requests
3. Wait for Facebook to expose more of the widget API so we can see what the hell is going on

   ```
   <div class="fb-page"
       data-adapt-container-width="false" <!-- This bit's the important part -->
       data-href="https://www.facebook.com/yourpage"
       data-show-posts="true"
       data-small-header="true"
       data-width="100%"
   >
       <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
           <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/yourpage"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/yourpage">Like YourPage on Facebook!</a></blockquote>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

combined with the following javascript:

```
    // FB Resize
    $(window).bind('resize', _.debounce(function() {

        if (window.FB && FB.XFBML && FB.XFBML.parse) {
            var el = $('.fb-page');
            var width = el.parent().width();
            el.attr('data-width', width);

            FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
    }, 1000)); // Debounce until 1000ms have passed
```

Answer (score 1):

This is JQuery and might be part of the answer to your question. I am using the HTML5 version of the like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="my.domain.com" data-layout="standard" data-send="false" data-width="255" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

The "div.main-content" element is the element that the like button must fit into in my design. The resizing works until to the div gets so small that the data-layout attribute in the div.fb-like needs to be changed from "standard" to an alternative that takes up less horizontal space. I am new at this, so I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution to making the like button repsonsive. I would like to see an answer to this question from somebody that is more of an expert on this subject.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var computed_width = $('div.main-content').width();    
  $('div.fb-like iframe').attr('style', 'border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height:  24px; width: ' + computed_width + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the inspect element to see what code is being generated. In some cases like Wordpress Facebook plugins they use different "ids" and once you find the id being used adding

```
 #fbSEOComments, #fbSEOComments iframe[style] {width: 100% !important;}
```

This doesnt always do the trick im learning. While you can change colors and some sizing making it responsive is still very buggy. It doesnt seem to like percentages and doesnt see the size of the box it's in so this isnt working. im toying with doing @media queries to resize it depending on the size of browser window.

It would be nice if it recognized the width but the @media seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook made some changes to the outputted markup from the comments plugin.  I am using the HTML5 version.  This amended CSS from what was shared above did the trick.

```
.fb-comments, .fb_iframe_widget iframe[style], .fb_iframe_widget span[style] {width: 100% !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some jquery that should persist across changes to the output markup as it uses a regex expression to rewrite the width only, leaving the rest of the style tag alone.

You need to specify the correct container id or selector, replacing my example of: #footer-last.  The iframe is resized based on the changes in width to the container, which will need to be set up as responsive.

```
// Resize facebook window width
container_width = $('#footer-last').width();
$fb_iframe = $('.fb-social-like-plugin iframe');
fb_style = $fb_iframe.attr('style').replace(/width:\s*\d+px/i, 'width: ' + container_width + 'px');
$fb_iframe.attr('style', fb_style);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the comments, but with the link box, all you have to do is use the iframe option direct from Facebook and switch out the width in pixels with a percentage, and it'll change depending on the width of the column it's in.

Comment: Wonder if that is a new capability? I'll test later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small work around that appends the HTML5 Facebook LikeBox Plugin into the DOM with a response height or width.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){      
            var height = $(window).height();
            var width = $(window).width();

            var widget_height = parseInt((height)*0.9);
            var widget_width = parseInt((height)*0.3);
            var page_url = "http://www.facebook.com/Facebook";

            $(".fb-plugin").append("<div class='fb-like-box' 
                                         data-href='"+page_url+"' 
                                         data-width='"+widget_width+"' 
                                         data-height='"+widget_height+"' 
                                         data-colorscheme='dark' 
                                         data-show-faces='true' 
                                         data-border-color='#222' 
                                         data-stream='true' 
                                         data-header='true'>
            </div></div>");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example, using jQuery, with a response width and a loading image.
The CSS code of Alan and Jubair is commented in the code.

That's works fine in an Android webview

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    .fb-comments, .fb-comments span, .fb-comments.fb_iframe_widget span iframe {
        width: 100%;/* !important; To get the control with JQuery*/
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
                appId   : 'APP_ID',
                channelUrl : '//domain.com/channelUrl.php',
                status  : true, 
                cookie  : true,
                xfbml   : true
            });

        //Event fired when the plugin has been completely loaded
        FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render',
            function(response) {
                //alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
                var w = (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')?
                           window.innerWidth
                        :(typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
                         && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
                         'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) ?
                           document.documentElement.clientWidth
                        : document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;

                w *= .950; //95% for best fit on mobile screens
                //RESIZE
                $(".fb-comments").css("width",w);
                $(".fb-comments > span").css("width",w);
                //Some days ago the next line would be sufficient                       
                $(".fb_ltr").css("width",w);
                //Now the modify of the span width is necessary to do the work

                $("#div_loading_gif").remove();



            }
        );

      };

      //cargando SDK Asíncronamente
      (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
      }(document));



    </script>

    <div id="div_loading_gif" style="width:100%;  height:100%; text-align:center; background:url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;" >

    </div>

    <!--Usando jquery modificar el style de el div de clase fb_ltr
    cambiar el ancho por el de la pantalla-->
    <div class="fb-comments"
        style="padding:0 auto;"
        data-href="http://domain.com/comments.html" 
        data-width="100px" 
        data-num-posts="5"
        data-mobile="false"
        >
    </div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `max-width` is better than `width` in this case, and it works for me:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
/* Set inline instead of inline-block */
.fb-comments.fb_iframe_widget{
    display: inline !important;
}

.fb-comments.fb_iframe_widget span,
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried this and it appears there is now a `<div>` within the `iframe` that has a fixed width, meaning you now actually need to remove the `style` tag with javascript to make it fluid.

EDIT: You can't access the iframe content with JS because it's coming from another domain

Comment: Think this is the only way to do it now
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22328835/2553149

Comment: Agreed with @blues_driven - that link is perfect.

Comment: This is the Facebook issue https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/256568534516879/

Comment: This issue has now been fixed by facebook, you can now set the width option to `100%` or add `data-width="100%`

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty div where you want the facebook like box to be (or other social plug-in, works universally) with a class 'fb-container', then add the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fb-container').replaceWith('<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://WWW.YOURSITEHERE.COM/" data-width="' + $('PARENT DIV').width().toFixed(0) +'" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>');
});
```

**p.s. you can replace PARENT DIV with any other element you want the comment box to match and WWW.YOURSITEHERE.COM with your site**

Comment: Not sure that works for the comments box as fb hard codes a pixel width inside its iframe, which can't be altered.

Comment: @JaydenLawson -> live example here (if you resize then refresh to get new width): http://whisperingforest.org/#/quote/40

Comment: The fb comments box didn't load on first attempt, which was odd. It loaded on refresh though. This is what I see when I resize the window: http://screencast.com/t/0Jrrw8EWZ. It's not loading on further refreshes.  I see what you mean though, and this does seem like a good solution. You just need to refresh the whole comments box on window resize.

Comment: @JaydenLawson -> check the answer, I edited with a new solution I found today while working on a client's site.. It works smoother now in a way that instead of trying to interrupt facebook's load.. it now loads it with a data-width tag set to a chosen div's width.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 $('.fb-comments').attr('data-width', '100%');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using a little jQuery and setting the "data-width" attribute when the page loads and on window resizing.  Problem I ran into with all the CSS approaches is that some of the comments and buttons were hidden outside the container's margins or overflowing.

Here's my $0.02, hope it helps.  Also, just set the #content selector to whatever you want the comment box to match such as a container div...

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
//check for device width and reformat facebook comments
function fbCommentWidth() {
    jQuery('.fb-comments').attr('data-width',jQuery('#content').width());

}
//run on resize, and reparse FB comments box    
jQuery(window).on('resize',function() {
    fbCommentWidth();
    FB.XFBML.parse();
});
//run on document ready
fbCommentWidth();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works: just add this data-width="100%"
Here is an example:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light" data-width="100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
(function() {
    window.addEventListener('load', updateWidth);
    window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(function () {
        updateWidth();
        if (window.FB && FB.XFBML && FB.XFBML.parse) {
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
    }, 1000));

    function updateWidth() {
        $('.fb-like, .fb-comments').each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            var width = el.parent().width();
            el.attr('data-width', width);
        })
    }

    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    }
})();
```