# How to make Facebook Comments have a fluid width of 100%?

Tags: html, css, facebook

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

This is how I generate the comments area after including the Facebook javascript SDK on the page:

```
<div class="fb-comments fb-comments-update" data-href="http://site.com" data-width="600" data-colorscheme="light" data-num-posts="10" data-order-by="social" data-mobile="auto-detect"></div>
```

As you can see facebook sets the width of the comments area based on this data attribute you give it:

```
data-width="600"
```

In this case I am telling facebook I want the area to be 600 pixels. But I am currenly building a responsive site and need the comments section to fit the width of the screen 100%. Doing none of these works:

```
data-width="100"
data-width="100%"
```

Is there any way to get a fluid width for facebook comments?

Comment: what will happend if you won't use `data-width` at all and set width in stylesheet?

Comment: @miszczu I tried changing it with css but can't figure it out.

Comment: do you have to use `data-width` to get comments? Can you style it in css file? If yes, I will give you css code for that.

Comment: @miszczu no you don't need that attribute for the comments to appear.

Comment: Ok the second answer on this question worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447483/how-to-make-facebook-comments-widget-a-fluid-width

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
<style>.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-like-box, .fb-like-box iframe[style] {width: 100% !important;}
.fb-comments span, .fb-comments iframe span[style], .fb-like-box span, .fb-like-box iframe span[style] {width: 100% !important;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

First size is for devices smaller then 1200px and bigger then 979px. The only problem is with IE sometimes, but you can use something like that: `width: 1200px\9;` - IE 8 and above

This sample is from [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), which I'm using very often. To use it you need less [win version](http://winless.org/). But this code works in aby browser (except old IE).

```
.fb-comments { width: 490px; /* or width: 50%; */ }

/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .fb-comments { width: 600px; /* or width: 50%; */ }
}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .fb-comments { width: 400px; /* or width: 50%; */ }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .fb-comments { width: 30px; /* or width: 50%; */ }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .fb-comments { width: 200px; /* or width: 50%; */ }
}
```

Also try to use percentage, not pixels, even with padding, for example:

```
.fb-comments { width: 90%; height: auto; padding: 0 5%; }
```

Comment: This no longer works due to Facebook setting the width of the comment box inside the iframe. Sigh/