# Responsive Facebook comments no longer working?

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-comments

Here is an old website I've done a year back and the facebook comment is suppose to shrink according to the screen width:

http://theupcoming.me/jflo-beatboxer-newyork-upcoming-youtube/

Previously it was working fine, however I visited the site today, noticed the css responsive hacks stop working and the width is default to 550px and the 550px is being set at the facebook server and I can't seem to rewrite the css any longer.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive Facebook Comments CSS Hack Broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187961/responsive-facebook-comments-css-hack-broken)

Comment: Just did this today. Here's a CSS-only solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187961/responsive-facebook-comments-css-hack-broken/24790169#24790169