# How to dynamically resize Facebook comments plugin using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

My DIV of showing the Facebook comments plugin (e.g. **.fb-comments**) is fixed by CSS, consider that if I cannot modify that CSS, is it possible to resize the comments plugin using pure JS solution after all comments are loaded?

```
 <div style='background-color:red;height:200px;' 
       class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" 
       data-num-posts="10"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8MyV3/1/

Comment: why can't you use css? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500424/is-it-possible-to-set-a-fluid-width-for-facebooks-social-plugins

Comment: you can modify the css from js i guess.

Answer (score 2):

It is very much possible.

The `.fb-comments` class is set via CSS, but you can still use the `!important` flag to overwrite it.

**Lets get to it:**

1. First you need to overwrite some CSS:

   ```
   .fb-comments, .fb-comments * {
       width:100% !important;
   }
   ```
2. Then you can place your facebook comments widget in its own container

   ```
   <div class="fb_container">
           <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="10"></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. *Optional* - Style it with CSS however you want:

   ```
   .fb_container{
      width: 200px;
   }
   ```
4. And then you can change it programatically with JS:

   ```
    $(".fb_container").css("width","200px");
   ```

Here's a [working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/fEW5c/)

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick:

```
$('.fb-comments').attr('data-width', '200');
```

That will make ".fb-comments" 200px wide.

Answer (score 0):

Need to update three elements to make fully resized.

```
$('.fb-comments').attr('data-width', '200');
$('.fb-comments span').css('width', '200');
$('.fb-comments span iframe').css('width', '200');
```