# Set value for dynamic class in CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, wordpress, css

I have Facebook Comment module installed in WordPress, for some unknown reason Facebook made some changes and now the class I need to change is dynamically as for example `#feedback_7324324h`, `#feedback_kjwyhr`, `#feedback_234734dsfn` and so on, the only equal part is `#feedback_` is there any way or chance to set width to 100% on any element that holds `#feedback_` as class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector (the hash at the beginning of the class seems strange ?)

```
jQuery('[id^="feedback_"]').css('width', '100%' );
```

Comment: Or use `*=` selector (contains substring) if the class attribute doesn't start with `#feedback_`. *([CSS version](http://jsbin.com/yuvor/2/edit))*

Comment: Didn't work, see example here http://ismaelcala.com/construyendo-puentes/ and look for the `#feedback_` still with `width: 100px`, why?

Comment: @ReynierPM - I can find neither elements or javascript matching a `#feedback_` class, I can however find an element matching the ID `feedback_`, so I'm guessing you're giving us the wrong info here. I edited the answer, but note that this element is inserted in an iframe from another domain, which you probably don't have access to.

Comment: Yes, was my bad talk about `#feedback_` and yes it's in a iframe element so jQuery code or CSS code doesn't work, what could be the solution in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure there is one, you don't have access to that iframe, but the iframe sets the width based on a parent element, so you'll just have to try and set the width of the container to 100% instead.

Comment: Love this idea but I guess it can't work as we won't have access to the facebook domain.  All fb need to do is give us a simple width control using percentages!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah like this

```
$("[class^='#feedback_']")
```

Docs `-->`  https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/