# Facebook social plugin on html5 page

Tags: css, html, facebook

I have no experience on any programming or webdesign but I had to revise a free html5 template for our website and I tried to add facebook plugin on it, the social plugin works fine in desktop version but width is static in mobile version, I have read other answers such as:

[Is it possible to set a fluid width for Facebook's social plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500424/is-it-possible-to-set-a-fluid-width-for-facebooks-social-plugins)

but I do not know where to add below codes recommended by other members.

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-comments span {
```

width: 100% !important;
}

here is our website: www.olympfitness.mn/4

Please tell us how we get it work on either desktop and mobile version, thank you and sorry for the broken english.

Comment: please include relevant code

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the code from here https://www.addthis.com/dashboard#gallery/ for social share and like.